# Modification of the subset sum problem - "perfect coverage" of the set with good solutions

Tags: co.combinatorics, algorithms, computational-complexity

I have a problem.

We have a set.

$S = (a_1, a_2 ... a_k)$ and an integer $x$.

We know that there is a sum of elements to $x$ in it.

We also know that:

- if there is only one sum to $x$ then it must contain all elements of the set;
- if there are many sums, elements from these sums must "ideally cover" all elements of the set.

For example, take the set $S = (1, 2, 3, 5, 7)$ and $x = 13$.

Possible sums up to 13 are:

$1 + 2 + 3 + 7 = 13$

$1 + 5 + 7 = 13$

These totals contain all elements of the $S$.

A bad example is the set $S = (1, 2, 3, 5, 7)$ and $x = 5$:

$2 + 3 = 5$

and

$5 = 5$

The set of elements adding up to 5 is therefore: $(2, 3, 5)$.

It is not identical to the set S.

Elements not "covered" in the set S are: $(1, 7)$.

In my issue, we always consider that the "perfect coverage" of the set exists.

We're looking for any subset that sums up to $x$.

How can we find him quickly?

Maybe someone knows the polynomial method?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not easier than searching solutions to the classsic SubsetSum problem. Here is a reduction: given a set $T$ of positive integers and a target integer $t$, let $m$ be the sum of elements of $T$ and wlog assume that $t\leq m$ and $2t\geq m$ (otherwise, replace $t$ with $m-t$). If this instance of SubsetSum search problem has a solution, then the set $S=T \cup \{ m+1, 2t+1\}$ and $x=t+m+1$ form an instance of the "perfect coverage" SubsetSum problem.

Indeed, the elements of $Z\subset T$ sum to $t$ iff the elements of $Z\cup \{ m+1\}$ sum to $x$ and the elements of $(T\setminus Z)\cup \{ 2t+1\}$ also sum to $x$. So the sums to $x$ cover all $S$. Furthermore, each sum to $x$ must contain either $m+1$ or $2t+1$, and so one can construct solutions to one instance from those to the other (and vice versa).

Comment: Let us assume that we have a set $S = (1, 2, 5, 7)$. Wanted $t = 11$. $m = 15$ (sum of elements). According to the above, $S '= (1, 2, 5, 7, 16, 23)$ and $x = 11 + 15 + 1 = 27$. However, $S'$ and $27$ do not have an "ideal coverage"? Do I count something wrong? I guess the point is that you can convert any set to a set with "perfect coverage"? But in the above case it does not work.

Comment: @Aurelio: I assumed the search (not decision) problem. Finding a solution to the constructed "perfect coverage" instance implies one to the original problem. Your SubsetSum instance has no solutions though. I've updated my answer to avoid confusion.